# Facebook bugs? 1) user picture url 2) authentication with cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a Facebook canvas application written on asp.net mvc. I can't see what's going on in facebook.

1. I have client-side code that loads FB user picture:

   FB.api('/' + userId, { fields: "id,link,name,picture" }, function (user) {
               $('img[data-fb-user-img]', subjectVoterElement).attr('src', user.picture.data.url);
           });

One day it responds picture url in user.picture, another day - in user.picture.data.url so i have errors time to time. Why FB gives different respond structure?
2.
To authorize FB user in my app i use facebook cookie being sent to my app server. Then i extract value from it, then parse the value with ParseSignedRequest method and exchange obtained code into token.
HttpCookie fbCookie = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies[
String.Format("fbsr_{0}", System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FB_Id"])];
                string code =
                    ((dynamic) FacebookService.FacebookService.Client.ParseSignedRequest(fbCookie.Value)).code;

```
            using (var webClient = new WebClient())  
            {  
                var result = webClient.DownloadString(  
                    String.Format(  
                        "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id={0}&redirect_uri=&client_secret={1}&code={2}",  
                        FacebookService.FacebookService.Client.AppId,  
                        FacebookService.FacebookService.Client.AppSecret,  
                        code  
                        )  
                    );
```

Sometimes i get authorization error saying the code is expired or specified user has logged off from facebook. In fact, i logged off a hour ago and since that moment this have already been worked successfull. Also, the facebook cookie expiration time is set long enough and hasnt come yet.
Does anyone have the same problem? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the issue with #1 or not but I have had issues so I will just throw it out there.  There are actually at least two different types of facebook users (could be more):

1. Regular facebook users that have accounts like you and me
2. Accounts that are just setup for a facebook page

How to create a facebook account that is just for a page?

- Step 1: Logout of your facebook account
- Step 2: Go here: http://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php
- Step 3: Setup a page for a fake business or whatever type of page you
  want to test with
- Step 4: Select I do not have a facebook account and create an account
  with a new email address

Now try your application with your regular user and with this facebook page only user.  Like I said, I am not sure if this is your problem or not but I have had a bunch of other problem with facebook page only accounts so it is could be worth a try.